# New build won't POST, no video/beeps

Tags: computer-building, post

Specs:

- **Motherboard**: MSI 760GM-P23 FX
- Integrated graphics (on MoBo)
- **CPU**: AMD Athlon II x4 640
- **RAM**: GeIL Pristine 4GB DDR3
- **Case/PSU**: TOPOWER TP-4107BB-400

Is not POSTing, no video output, no beeps. When RAM is removed, 3 beeps. I have tried removing and replacing the CPU and all the power cables with no change. Resetting the BIOS (by removing and replacing the battery) did nothing as well.

Is there something I'm forgetting (1st time building from components), or could one of the components be bad?

**New development**: with CPU and RAM installed correctly, it will turn on lights and fans (still no POST) and after running for a minute or so it will turn off and the PSU will make a buzzing noise that ceases only when unplugged.

Comment: Sounds like a dumb question, but did you forget the 4-Pin motherboard power? its separate from the ATX 24-pin one.

Whenever this happens to me, it always seems to be i forgot to hook that one up.

Comment: @JaredTritsch yes, the 4-pin power connector is attached correctly

Comment: Ah okay, nevermind about that then...

Comment: do the fans or any LEDs come up when you power it? if not triple check your power wiring. if still no fans, sounds like an RMA to me.

Comment: @FrankThomas All LEDs and fans come on as normal

Comment: Try one stick of memory at a time. Sometimes a bad stick of ram can have a similar affect.

Comment: @PhillipR. There's only one stick of RAM in this build

Comment: Do you have any other known good memory? That would work? Or maybe test that stick in a known good computer if possible? Basically the steps I would take would be to switch out each part with known good. Or attempt to put each part in a known good computer.

Comment: @PhillipR. Unfortunately no, my other computers are DDR and DDR2; this one is DDR3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was a RAM issue. It boots just fine with the new stick of RAM I bought. I guess I need to stop going for the cheapest parts all the time. ☺

Comment: Glad you figured it out. That is what I was suspecting also, but without the ability to test other sticks and such makes it difficult.